# why preventdefault/stopPropagation not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a demo application where preventdefault/stopPropagation .Not sure where I am doing wrong .Using Jquery it is working fine.Follow the below steps to reproduce the bug

1. Run the application and click on `button`.

when I put jQuery code it works perfectly . it only show `'jquery:: 1'` on console not showing

`'jquery:: 2'` as expected because we used `e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();`

```
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.bclink[href*="bcid="]', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('jquery:: 1')
    })
      
      jQuery(document).on('click', '.clickvideo', function(e){
        // detect .clickvideo-overlay parent to prevent spawning of additional w10 lightboxes
        console.log('jquery:: 2')
        
    });
```

but same code when I used in javascript and click `button` it console both `JS:::1` and `JS:::2`.why prevent default not works

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
    function handler(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
       console.log("JS:::1")
    }
    
    for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
        if (target.matches('.bclink[href*="bcid="]')) {
            handler.call(target, e);
            break;
        }
    }
}, false)







 document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
    function handler(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
       console.log("JS::: 2")
    }
    
    for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
        if (target.matches('.clickvideo')) {
            handler.call(target, e);
            break;
        }
    }
}, false)
})
```

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/riwazorine/edit?html,css,js,output

Expected output : it only show `"JS:::1"`  as I used preventdefault and stopPropagation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS, both event listeners are attached to the same element - the document. `stopPropagation` only stops event propagation to *other* elements (ancestors or descendants), but not to the *same* elements.

You need `stopImmediatePropagation`, which stops other event handlers on the same element from running.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
  function handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log("JS:::1")
  }

  for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
    if (target.matches('.bclink[href*="bcid="]')) {
      handler.call(target, e);
      break;
    }
  }
}, false)




document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
  function handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("JS::: 2")
  }

  for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
    if (target.matches('.clickvideo')) {
      handler.call(target, e);
      break;
    }
  }
}, false)
```

```css
.bcthumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="bcthumbnail clickvideo bcimgadded" data-bcid="6086922094001"><a href="?bcid=6086922094001" class="bclink" title="Autonomous Infrastructure: Larry Ellison at Oracle OpenWorld 2019"><button class="vjs-big-play-button"></button>button</a></div>
```

Also, rather than your `for` loo, you can use `.closest` instead, it's a whole lot cleaner.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('.bclink[href*="bcid="]')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log("JS:::1")
  }
})
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.clickvideo')) {
    console.log("JS::: 2")
  }
})
```

```css
.bcthumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="bcthumbnail clickvideo bcimgadded" data-bcid="6086922094001"><a href="?bcid=6086922094001" class="bclink" title="Autonomous Infrastructure: Larry Ellison at Oracle OpenWorld 2019"><button class="vjs-big-play-button"></button>button</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering will this `e.target.closest('.clickvideo')) {` is generic .previously I was using this `delegate` method genric one http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: generic mean will I pass `class, id , data attribute`